# Something interesting happening for an implicit curve

Tags: calculus

Suppose $y^2+2xy = x^3-5x+3$. I was tasked with finding the horizontal and vertical tangent points of this curve which are approximately $(-0.643211,-1.879420)$, $(-2.245678,5.064605)$ (horizontal tangent lines) and $(-3,3)$ (vertical tangent line). But $(1,-1)$ is where the curve intersects with itself. My question is what does this mean (because if we didn’t know what plot looked like then this point would be a vertical tangent point line)???
Thanks.

Comment: To discover this effect, solve your equation for $y$

Comment: Oh right doing so we see that this is where both curves touch each other so it can’t be a point where there is a tangent line.

Comment: If you were to parameterize this curve, you would find two tangents at $(1,-1)$ but neither is horizontal or vertical. The gradient of $y^2+2xy-x^3+5x-3$ vanishes entirely there, which is why this point turns up as a solution if you’re looking for points at which either $dy/dx$ or $dx/dy$ is zero.